# mixed C#/C++ - why is the build output telling me to change the C# target platform to X64?

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild

I have a solution with 3 `C#` projects and one `C++` project. After changing the `C++` project configuration to x64, the build fails with:

```
"Error  27  Please change your target platform to x64 via Build -> Configuration Manager"
```

for each `C#` project. I should mention that neither of the C# projects reference/`[dllimport]` the C++ project.
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Project dependencies perhaps? What is the reason of putting unrelated C++ project together into same solution?

Comment: @Sinatr After I get the solution to build I intend to call the C++ project from one of the C# projects

Comment: How would you call 64 bit library code from 32 bit application? Given error makes perfect sense then.

Comment: @Sinatr it's configured as Any CPU at the time being. Besides, not every native library included in my solution must be called by the executables, I might want to release it as a stand alone library